# give select value to php wodpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to give value from this input:

```
<select name="sample" id="select_rent" class="select" style="border-radius: 6px; padding: 10px; padding-right:40px;">
    <option value="<?php   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price_1', true ); ?>">1</option>
    <option value="<?php   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price_3', true ); ?>">3</option>
    <option value="<?php   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price_6', true ); ?>">6</option>
    <option value="<?php   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price_12', true ); ?>">12</option>
    <option value="<?php   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price_24', true ); ?>">24</option>
</select>
```

to this php code (as variable `select_value`):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    // This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example | optional)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $select_value );
    }
}
```

I've got this raw ajax and don't know what to do:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $('#select_rent').change(function () {
                        var workselected = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "url",
                            data: $('#select_rent').val(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log($('#select_rent').val());
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })
    </script>
```

ajax isn't working `400 (Bad Request)` and I don't know how to give value to php. Can anybody help?

I fixed ajax, now it console logs value. How can I give it to php?

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax url to: `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');` with the specific action name, for example: `get_data`

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
     data: {
         action:'get_data' ,
         select_rent : $('#select_rent').val(),
     },
     success: function (data) {
           console.log($('#select_rent').val());
     }
});
```

this will send your data to the WordPress ajax handler and WordPress will call the actions u defined already in `function.php` or someWhere else .

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'my_ajax_handler' );

function my_ajax_handler() {
   //whatever you want to do;
   return $result ;
}
```

now in `//whatever you want to do;` you must somehow save the value is recived to this function by ajax call. for example you can do this actions :

- save it in the DB
- save in in session
- keep it in settings
- persist it in redis
- etc

now its time to define your final action :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    // fetch previously saved data and do whatever you want with it.
}
```

Comment: Help for your reply! Can I just json encode data and use it? I want to us it like this: `$_POST['data']` but if I echo it - it's empty.

Comment: U must echo `select_rent` not `data` . And yes you can get the select_rent with post parameter in `my_ajax_handler` function.